# Loading next item from the close vote queue takes longer and longer

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, performance

As a regular close vote review tasks handler I'm pretty used to the user experience, including the performance of load times of the next review task.

When reviewing close votes I'm always filtered on [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and off-topic. I primarily use IE11 as my browser on WIN7.

The last week or so I notice that loading the next review tasks takes a considerable amount of time up to 20 seconds. I do notice that in that case I get a [review for a question that is 5 months old](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2773083).

Can this be investigated or explained and maybe tuned?

Comment: It's to allow the robo-reviewers to go through the checkout lane before the other queues

Comment: @Oded I know this is somehow resolved but I get now and then reports that loading of items is slow. Any chance you can check if some queries times out? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16918360#16918360

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 35.0.1 on Win7.

Comment: Using Chrome on Win7. I find that post loading is a function of time: the older the post is, the longer it takes to load. Posts for "today" load within a second, 1+ months ago take 10+ seconds.