# Very low performance of SO close review queue when using filtering by tag

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, review, tag-filters, performance

I've just altered the tag filter in close review queue on StackOverflow to [dojo](/questions/tagged/dojo), because questions tagged [dojo](/questions/tagged/dojo) and not [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) were normally skipped by my filter.

Unfortunatelly, the next question in review queue takes very long time to load. It looks like there was no tag indexing in review queue or it was poorly implemented.

Please inspect the problem and fix it.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221614/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-takes-longer-and-longer From Oded: " Those queries, in particular filtered ones do not play very nice with the DB. We do intend to fix things, once we got to this bit of the site. "