# Stack Overflow 'review' button is slow, and test questions are slower

Tags: bug, review

In the last few weeks, the 'review' button at the top of stackoverflow.com has become very slow. I can count to 20 in some cases (but not always).

In a perhaps related phenomenon, I believe that test questions in the queue often trigger a level of extreme slowness all their very own. If I click on a queue, or 'next' after a review, and the periods sit there throbbing for a good long time, chances are that what will show up will be a review audit.

Comment: Related: [Loading next item from the close vote queue takes longer and longer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221614/237685)

Comment: I've noticed this only on SO. Chrome (latest) Windows 8.1.

Comment: Same on [math.se]. By the time an edit audit loads, I already know what it is, and am hovering over reject button with some impatience.

Comment: Happens here for SO, too. On Win 8.1 with a 150MB upstream and downstream internet connection as well as on my iPad at home with a total different connection. Since approx. 2-3 weeks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the next build, review performance been improved with some much needed caching.  Some days you just can't have enough cache!

Comment: Geoff, caching appears broken today: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253972/accessing-the-review-queue-is-slow

Comment: @gnat is correct, accessing https://stackoverflow.com/review took over two minutes for the second time today so was going to report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It seems to be working now. Currently i´m getting a lightning fast response.

Comment: It's still unstable and audits are still [reported to take long time to load](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255703).