# Loading next item from the Close Vote Queue ends in an error

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

I'm filtering on a specific tag in the CVQ over on SO where I'm pretty sure the queue doesn't have much review tasks left.

After the [loading takes incrementaly longer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221614/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-takes-longer-and-longer)<sup>1</sup> on every next item from the queue I'm finally greeted with:

[image]

I assume this is because the queue is emptied. On prior occasions I was greeted with this message:

> There are no items for you to review, matching the filter "[angularjs]"

A retry (clicking next item) or reload doesn't solve the issue.

On Nov, 22th there was a [similar situation reported in chat by @TGMCians](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2693345#2693345)

#### Individual reports <sup>2</sup>

- [Nov 30th, 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6023747)
- [Nov 30th, 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6148037)
- [????, 20:15](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6490363)
- [Dev 28th, aprox 19:47](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20675279#20675279) (@TGMCians)
- [Dec 28th, 19:57](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2cJg.png)
- Dec 30th, 20:03
- Dec 31th, 18:44
- Feb 2nd 2015 18:35
- [Feb 2nd, 18:50](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6861234)
- [Feb 2nd, 18:55](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6895062)
- [Feb 3rd, 21:24](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6850893)
- [Feb 4th, 19:19](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6947751)
- [Apr 9th, 19:42](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7550805)
- [Apr 13th, 19:58](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22657429#22657429)
- [Apr 15th, ~ 03:32](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22702429#22702429)
- [Apr 22th, 20:19](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7771622)
- [May 4th, 17:38](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7923582)
- [May 5th, 20:30](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7946324)
- [May 18th, 18:38](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8060684)
- [May 27th, 19:42](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8210330)
- [May 30th, 19:25](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8262747)
- [Jun, 9th, 19:56](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8349621)

#### 2016

- [Mar, 7th, 6:25](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318414/660921)
- [Mar, 11th, 20:33](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11584547)
- [Mar, 12th, 18:08](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11605369)
- [Mar, 16th, 18:58](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11623293)
- [Mar, 23th, 20:06](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11746755)

I see this behavior in Chrome on Win7/x64 but couldn't repro on Dec 1st, 2014 in IE11.

Can this be investigated?

*footnotes*

<sup>1. the linked question isn't a dupe. There was no error shown in that scenario, now there is.</sup>
<sup>2. the link points the last review item that did load succesful, if available, all times in UTC</sup>

Comment: +1 I reported here also http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2693345#2693345 start to read from here but no response of you guys

Comment: @TGMCians although devs and mods might monitor chat (specially the tavern) it isn't the official bug report channel which might explain why it wasn't picked up... I included your link in my post as extra evidence that this isn't an one-off....