# voting to close on iPad takes 40 seconds

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app, ipad

It appears to take about 20 seconds (timed) to render the dialog and then when you select the close reason and click the 'vote' link another 20 seconds to complete.  This has been the case for at least 2 weeks since I started using the iPad app.

Edit: This is on an iPad mini (about 9 months old) running iOS 8.1.1

Comment: I use iPod 4th gen and never had a problem like this...

Comment: Current gen iPad mini running iOS 8.1.1

Comment: How other things work for you? Loading questions, posting answers, posting comments, voting, etc.?

Comment: And how does it work for you from the website? I have two open bugs on load times of review items. [This one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244335/loading-next-item-from-the-close-vote-queue-ends-in-an-error) is the latest report.

Comment: When using the web interface to SO on the iPad, instead of the iOS app, the close dialog comes up instantly.  In safari or chrome it behaves the same as when using the web interface on my desktop.

Comment: Everything else besides the flag dialog works very well.

Comment: I noticed this issue, too. The other functions, and access from the website, are not slow at all. It's just the voting through the iPad app.

Comment: This appears to be fixed.  Should I delete the question or post and accept an answer to that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not been able to reproduce this.  It's possible that we either improved performance or something happened like the API restarting.

Comment: This hasn't been a problem in quite a while.